# Argument in revolve of GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql

I was learning GraphQL, to be particular, I was following udemy course by stephen Grinder.

In his video he used 3rd Argument in revolve

```
resolve(parent, args, request) {
```

> request object have details such as what route they were trying to
>   access, query string and body etc. (used in authentication)

Which I found to be sort of vaguely explained

So I googled and read this from graphQL page

> This example is written in JavaScript, however GraphQL servers can be
>   built in many different languages. A resolver function receives four
>   arguments:
>
> **obj** The previous object, which for a field on the root Query type is
>   often not used.
>
> **args** The arguments provided to the field in the
>   GraphQL query.
>
> **context** A value which is provided to every resolver and
>   holds important contextual information like the currently logged in
>   user, or access to a database.
>
> **info** A value which holds field-specific
>   information relevant to the current query as well as the schema
>   details, also refer to type GraphQLResolveInfo for more details.

Now, I am unable to comprehend when do we need to use context/request? since it is used in mutation, I have a feeling that it will pass information from **graphQL to my passport-express** (since our actual intention in that route is get input from front end and pass it to passport local strategy)

But According to definition it appears that it is being used to pass information from **express to graphQL**

Also, since I stumbled upon graphQl docs, I also saw info, which I was again unable to comprehend.

So can someone please explain me context and info in graphQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can send basically any data you want along to the resolvers.

I verify tokens and add my user to the request, and then pass my user into the context as shown below.

```
const server  = new ApolloServer({schema: schema(), context: ({req}) => ({context: 
req.user})});
```

Then I have all user data available at my disposable:

```
 saveChat: async (root, {chat}, {context, pubsub}) => {
  const user = context || null;
  chat.author = user._id ? user._id : null;
  return new ChatModel({...chat}).save();
},
```

I also was testing some pubsub stuff and sending it through the context also.

It can also be handy when using graphql directives to determine roles and authority:

```
hasRole(next, src, {roles}, {context}) {
 if (!context) { throw new Error('Must be Authenticated at least.'); }
 let valid  = false;
 roles.forEach((role) => { valid = !valid ? _.includes(context.roles, role) : 
 valid; });
 return valid ? next() : new Error(`Missing correct role to perform this task, you 
 have roles: ${context.roles}`);
},
```

And in Graphql:

```
 directive @hasRole(roles: [String]) on FIELD_DEFINITION

 saveChat(chat: ChatSaveInput!): Chat @hasRole(roles: ["admin"])
```

This is loosely based off articles by Ryan Chenkie who has done a few about with & graphql, Worth a look.

Comment: Ryann,Thanks for answering. It appears you happen to be an experience dev and hence your answer appears to be sort of technical. 
Can you please explain me in terms of `resolve` taking four parameters `resolve(parent, args, context, info)`

Comment: What can I expect `context` (doing console.log gave me insane amount of stuff in console) and where is it coming from? like is express sending data in context or is it the client?

Comment: It's likely the Request your looking at Varun,